# AWS CDK resource create sequence?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm using the AWS CDK. When I deploy, according to CloudFormation Events in the AWS console, `resources(CfnTrigger)` in `createWorkflow` are initialized before `createDDBCrawler` and `createS3Crawler`. Which is causing `create_failed(Entity not found)` since `createWorkflow` depends on resources in these two.

So I am wondering:

1. AWS CDK resource generating sequence (since I see no `async` or `promise` in functions, so TypeScript is handling the code in sequence. Then it's a CDK/CloudFormation behavior?)
2. How to avoid this or arrange resource create sequence, except creating two stack.

```js
export class QuicksightGlue extends Construct {

    constructor(scope: Construct, name: string, props: QuicksightGlueProps) {
        super(scope, name);
        this.createGlueDb(props.glueDb);

        for (let zone of zones) {

            const ddbCrawler = this.createDDBCrawler(...);

            const etlJob = this.createEtlJob(...);

            // crawler for processed data
            this.createS3Crawler(...);  

            // create workflow that use crawler
            this.createWorkflow(...);      
        }
    }
```

```js
private createS3Crawler(...) {
        return new glue.CfnCrawler(this, 's3Crawler_' + zone, {
            name: 's3Crawler_' + zone,
            databaseName: glueDb,
            role: roleArn,
            targets: {
                s3Targets: [{ path: s3 }]
            }
        });
    }
private createWorkflow(...) {
        const extracDdbWorkflow = new glue.CfnWorkflow(this, `ExtractDdb_` + zone, {
            name: `udhcpExtractDdb_` + zone.toLowerCase(),
            description: "Workflow to extract and process data from DDB"
        });

        const scheduledTriggerDdbCrawler = new glue.CfnTrigger(this, 'DdbTrigger_' + zone, {
            workflowName: extracDdbWorkflow.name,
            type: "SCHEDULED",
            schedule: scheduleCronExpression, //"cron(0 * * * ? *)",
            description: "Trigger to start the workflow every hour to update ddb data",
            actions: [{
                crawlerName: ddbCrawler,
                }],
        });
...
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of `createWorkflow` and `createS3Crawler`?

Comment: @Hcaertnit updated in the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cause a construct to become dependent on another construct by calling `addDependency` on the construct's `node` property, like this:

```js
// Normally these two constructs would be created in parallel
const construct1 = ...;
const construct2 = ...;

// But with this line, construct2 will not be created until construct 1 is
construct2.node.addDependency(construct1);
```

[Here](https://github.com/davidtucker/ps-serverless-app/blob/e44782b565da447412bcdce969659fd52c429d45/infrastructure/lib/core/webapp.ts#L87) is a practical example.

---

Probably, you'd want to save the return value of `createS3Crawler` to a variable, and then pass that variable as an argument to `createWorkflow`.  Then, `createWorkflow` will call `.node.addDependency(createS3Crawler)` on each construct that it creates internally which is dependent on the S3 crawler.

Comment: thanks, I add the dependency between each trigger and workflow, it works.
(Adding dependency between crawler and workflow doesn't work, trigger still got initialized before crawlers)